# How many ways are there to make a schedule of 6 subjects

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 6 different subjects including maths and physics.

How many ways are there to make a schedule of 6 subjects such that physics follows maths?

Actually I tried to denote maths as M and physics as P.
Then I started to count like this.

MXXXXX - number of ways  - 5!

XMXXXX - number of ways  - 4*1*4*3*2*1 = 96

XXMXXX - number of ways  - 4*3*1*3*2*1 = 72

XXXMXX - number of ways  - 4*3*2*1*2*1 = 48

XXXXMX - number of ways  - 4*3*2*1*1*1 = 24

And then sum them up, getting 360, but actually the correct answer to the problem is 240.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Follow immediately after, or somewhere after? If immediately after, then simply "attach them together" as a single subject, then you have $5$ subjects instead of $6$, then there are $5!$ ways to arrange them. If somewhere after, then simply divide the total number of ways ($6!$) by $2$, since physics can equally likely come before math and after math.

Comment: Are you sure it isnt $120$

Comment: Yes correctly asked @barak manos

Comment: @barakmanos  You should turn your symmetry argument into an answer.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Done :)

Comment: Your answer is good.  Are you sure that this was exactly the question?  If you aren't allowed to take maths first thing, then you get 240 possible schedules.

Comment: The only way to arrive at an answer of 240 seems to be that Physics follows Math (360 ways) *but is not immediately following* (less 120 ways) to arrive at 240 = 360-120 ways. Check the precise wording of the question.

Comment: Maybe the intended wording was "That one follows the other" or something so that P follows M directly or M follows P directly, in that case it would be $5! *2=240$

Answer (score 11):

The total number of ways for arranging those $6$ subjects is $6!=720$.

Physics may equally likely appear before Math and after Math.

So there are $720/2=360$ arrangements with Physics after Math.

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is correct.

There are six slots to fill.  We can fill two of those six slots with mathematics and physics in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways.  Since physics must follow maths, there is only one way to arrange mathematics and physics in those slots.  For each of these ways of scheduling maths and physics, there are $4!$ ways of arranging the other subjects in the four remaining slots.  Hence, the number of possible schedules in which physics follows mathematics is 
$$\binom{6}{2} \cdot 4! = 360$$
as you found.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct. Another method leading to the same result:

$$\binom62\times4!=15\times24=360$$

From $6$ spots first select $2$ for maths and physics. Then place the other subjects in some order. There are $4!$ orders.

Comment: Actually I understand that my approach to the problem is correct. However   the issue is that the correct answer is 240 rather than 360. Could you please explain why is the answer 240.

Comment: @Marie Sometimes the solution key is incorrect.

Comment: Everybody here agrees with your answer. I don't think that's a coincidence ;) and fully agree with @N.F.Taussig. No idea how "they" come to $240$.

Answer (score 3):

There are 6! = 720 ways to order the six subjects.  Half these orderings will have math before physics.

Answer (score 2):

Choose 2 slots for m and p: $\binom{6}{2}$, this accounts for the fact that p follos m. For each such choice you have 4! allocations of other subjects

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is 240 because:

Imagine the math and physics classes together as a "package", they can be thought of as one two hour long class following each other. Considering that, there will be 5!=120 different schedules. However, within the "physics-math class", you can take physics first or math first, so there are 2!=2 ways to do that. Therefore, the total possible schedules are:

```
       5!2!=240 schedules possible
```

We solved a very similar problem in precalculus recently

Comment: You overlooked the requirement that physics follows maths.

Comment: No, read it over again. That is where the 2! comes in.

Comment: I was not referring to your answer.  The question states "How many ways are there to make a schedule of 6 subjects such that physics follows maths?"

Comment: So did you get the answer to be 5!=120 schedules

Comment: That would be the correct answer if physics had to immediately follow maths.  If physics has to appear somewhere after maths in the schedule, then the answer is $360$.  The wording is, alas, ambiguous.

Comment: Sure, sounds good